# Why does hover pseudo-selector on universal/wildcard selector seem to not apply?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, wildcard, pseudo-element

#### Minimal Reproducable Example

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   div {
    background-color: #F00;
   }
   * button {
    opacity: 0;
   }
   *:hover button {
    opacity: 1;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button>hello</button>
  <div>
   <button>world</button>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

#### Expected Behaviour vs Actual Behaviour

- I would expect the button with text "world" to appear when I hover my mouse over the red div.
- Instead I see there is no effect.
- I get exactly the same behaviour in Chrome and Safari.
- Interestingly, before I made the above into a separate HTML file, and ran it in chrome/safari, I tried that exact snippet in JSFiddle, and it works perfectly there (same browser).
- If I change the line `*:hover button` to `div:hover button` I get the expected behaviour.

#### My Envrionment

- Google Chrome - Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- MacOS Cataline - Version 10.15.5
- Safari Version 13.1.1

#### My Question(s)

- Is this a bug with Chrome AND Safari (seems pretty unlikely)
- Failing the above, is there something I am not understanding about how CSS works in this particular case? (Perhaps this use-case isn't supported in the official spec??)
- If the above is the case (why does this work in JSFiddle, but not as a standalone HTML file opened in chrome.

Comment: are you adding the doctype declaration when using html file?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I didn't, no, will that make a difference?

Comment: daaaamn!!! That fixed it. Thanks. Out of curiosity. Why is this the case?

Comment: I am finding the related question that explain this. We call it quirks mode and it makes a lot of difference

Comment: Wow! I never realised that, you learn something new ever day. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to @TemaniAfif for this (see comments in the question).

The answer is that you need to declare a doctype at the top of the HTML file. Without it, various browsers will render the page in "quirks mode" which allows backwards compatibility with older websites.